# How to identify the change in user or user type in Force.com site page

Tags: apex, force.com-sites, user

There is any possibility to identify change in logged in user from Portal/Community User type to Site User type.
Scenario is portal user being forced logged out through apex based on some logic but in UI that end user need to get pop up message, my idea is to provide message if I can identify change in user type!!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on your Site's architecture.

On a Single Page Application polling server data with Javascript, you 
could monitor the User.userType field with JavaScript's Time.setInterval and the Ajax Toolkit, by polling a custom apex page or apex rest webservice every 5 secs for example.

```
super complex code
```

Otherwise on a more classic Site, you could check each time your user loads a page
what his type is then fire a javascript popup.

Something like this, in pseudo-visualforce

```
<apex:page>
    <script> if ( true == {! $User.userType == 'guest' }) alert("logged off!"); </script>
</page>
```

Comment: As it runs continuous interval will it be any impact or performance issue?

Comment: I updated my answer: what kind of architecture do you use ?

Comment: Thanks Martin, I was using Java script and wanted to check if anything else we can do without monitoring the user properties - looks like it is the only option.  Thank you!